# How to bind a ComboBox to generic dictionary via ObjectDataProvider

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, combobox

I want to fill a ComboBox with key/value data in code behind, I have this:

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="TestCombo234.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestCombo234"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="Choices" ObjectType="{x:Type local:CollectionData}" MethodName="GetChoices"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Choices}}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TestCombo234
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }

    public static class CollectionData
    {
        public static Dictionary<int, string> GetChoices()
        {
            Dictionary<int, string> choices = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            choices.Add(1, "monthly");
            choices.Add(2, "quarterly");
            choices.Add(3, "biannually");
            choices.Add(4, "yearly");
            return choices;
        }
    }
}
```

**What do I have to change so that the key is the int and the value is the string?**

Comment: Google reveals this:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/6f9ff9a9-9133-40cc-bfdb-a47d340658bf

Comment: Looks like the image in your question above is broken (and now [showing an ad instead](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263771/ban-imageshack-images-because-they-are-reusing-old-urls-for-advertising)). Could you please reupload the image to stack.imgur, or edit your question to remove it?

Answer (score 134, accepted):

To your ComboBox add

```
SelectedValuePath="Key" DisplayMemberPath="Value"
```

Comment: I think you mean SelectedValuePath and DisplayMemberPath, those worked for me at least, thanks.

Comment: Oops, yes I did. I'll fix the answer.

Comment: In addition, `SelectedValue="{Binding myViewModelProperty}"` is good to add too if you want to get the user's selection.

Answer (score 7):

There's an easier way.

Convert the enumeration to a Generic.Dictionary object. For example let say you wanted a combo box with the weekday ( just convert the VB to C#)

```
Dim colWeekdays As New Generic.Dictionary(Of FirstDayOfWeek, String)
    For intWeekday As FirstDayOfWeek = vbSunday To vbSaturday
       colWeekdays.Add(intWeekday, WeekdayName(intWeekday))
    Next

RadComboBox_Weekdays.ItemsSource = colWeekdays
```

In your XAML you only need to set the following to bind to an object:

```
SelectedValue="{Binding Path= StartDayNumberOfWeeek}"  SelectedValuePath="Key" 
DisplayMemberPath="Value" />
```

The code above can easily be generalized using reflection to handle any enumerations.

hope this helps