# Bind ComboBox to Dictionary and the Selected to the Dictionary Key

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding, dictionary, combobox

How to bind the Selected to Dictionary Key?
The formatting of the Value may change.
Dictionary is char, string

```
<ComboBox
        Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" 
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Page}}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DLchars}"
        VerticalAlignment="Center" >
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="25"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>                                  
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=Key}" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Value}" />
            </Grid>                            
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605845/how-to-bind-a-combobox-to-generic-dictionary-via-objectdataprovider.

Use converter to change formatting

Comment: See the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334128/binding-a-dictionarys-key-and-value-in-a-listbox-with-wpf. Maybe help.

Comment: @AnatoliyNikolaev Yes that led to the answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer based on comment link from Anatoliy

```
<ComboBox
       Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3"
       DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Page}}"
       ItemsSource="{Binding  Path=DLchars}" 
       PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel="High"
       VerticalAlignment="Center" 
       SelectedValuePath="Key"
       SelectedValue="{Binding Path=EOL}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="25"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>                                  
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=Key}" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Value}" />
            </Grid>                            
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```