# Get Key from Value from Bound CheckBox

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a wpf desktop app.

I have a combox box and it is bound to a dictionary object.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyData}" DisplayMemberPath="Value.Login" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedUser }" SynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" />
```

and in my VM:

```
public Dictionary<string,UserRecord> Users
{
    get
    {
        return 'A Dictionary Defined Data'
    }
        set { _Users = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Users"); }
    }
}

public UserRecord SelectedUser
{
   get { return _SelectedUser; }
   set { _SelectedUser = value;
         RaisePropertyChanged(InformedWorkerCommon.Constants.VM_SelectedUser);
   }
}
```

The error I get when i select an item from the dropdown is:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 23 : Cannot convert '[ADMIN, UI.InformedWorkerViewModel.UserRecord]' from type 'KeyValuePair`2' to type 'UI.InformedWorkerViewModel.UserRecord' for 'en-US' culture with default conversions; consider using Converter property of Binding. NotSupportedException:'System.NotSupportedException: TypeConverter cannot convert from System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[UI.InformedWorkerViewModel.UserRecord, UI, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].
   at System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.GetConvertFromException(Object value)
   at System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)
   at MS.Internal.Data.DefaultValueConverter.ConvertHelper(Object o, Type destinationType, DependencyObject targetElement, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isForward)'
System.Windows.Data Error: 7 : ConvertBack cannot convert value '[ADMIN, UI.InformedWorkerViewModel.UserRecord]' (type 'KeyValuePair`2'). BindingExpression:Path=HeartBeat.CommonData.LogIn.SelectedUser; DataItem='ApplicationViewModel' (HashCode=43160662); target element is 'MetroComboBox' (Name=''); target property is 'SelectedItem' (type 'Object') NotSupportedException:'System.NotSupportedException: TypeConverter cannot convert from System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[UI.InformedWorkerViewModel.UserRecord, UI, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].
   at MS.Internal.Data.DefaultValueConverter.ConvertHelper(Object o, Type destinationType, DependencyObject targetElement, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isForward)
   at MS.Internal.Data.ObjectTargetConverter.ConvertBack(Object o, Type type, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.ConvertBackHelper(IValueConverter converter, Object value, Type sourceType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
```

I originally was using a List and it all worked but I needed to use the Dictionary collection type instead.  I am just stumped (and Googling) for a solution.

Any pointers/education i would appreciate.

Thanks!

Comment: @MetroSmurf thanks and will delete if appropiate

Comment: @closers that solutuion from that duplicate answr made no difference. it did not work for me

Comment: @closers my fault i did not read properly. wil delete ina second after I said thanks to other poster :)

Comment: @closers. i just tried to delete and I could not.  People need to vote this down sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell your combobox what do display and what to hold as a value:

```
SelectedValuePath="Value" DisplayMemberPath="Key"
```

Right now, since you are using a `Dictionary<string, UserRecord>`, your combobox is going to return one item from the dictionary as the `SelectedValue`. That one item is a `KeyValuePair<string, UserRecord>` and therefore it cannot be casted to a `UserRecord` (this is what the error is complaining about).

Comment: that made no difference I am afraid. Same error :(

Comment: your edit made sense but still do not know how to correct

Comment: try switching Key for Value and vice versa

Comment: @AndrewSimpson even with the switch it does not work?

Comment: Hello, sorry it did work with the swicth. But this would duplicate the other answr that some one kindly linked so need to delete thanks

Comment: Does that answer provide a reason and explanation for why?

Comment: Hi, no not a why bu the answer is the same as your yours.

Answer (score 0):

[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605845/how-to-bind-a-combobox-to-generic-dictionary-via-objectdataprovider)

```
DisplayMemberPath="Value"
```

I think this can work

Comment: key not value^^

Comment: If this question is a duplicate of the question you've linked here, please flag it as a duplicate with the "flag" button under the question instead of leaving an answer to that effect. If it is not a duplicate, then please leave a complete answer instead of a link-only answer

Comment: lol sorry multi-typing here to different things please ignore it