# How to group single ComboBox items to a group in same combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, grouping

I Have a enumeration class `Status`, which has `enum` values(say X, Y, Z, A, B, C) and these values are set in another class based on certain conditions.

Now I would like to create new comboBox item `GroupM` which would display A, B, C and similarly item `GroupN` which would display rows related to X, Y, Z:

[image]

How can I achieve that? I believe this may be vague requirement but this is the maximum I can explain.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grouping items in a combobox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585017/grouping-items-in-a-combobox)

Comment: Hi this is not the duplicate of what I asked. I am asking that A,B,C,X,Y,Z are 6 rows obtained from enumeration. So on clicking of GroupM I should display all 3 rows A,B,C. It is not a Category and Elelment or Tree View which I am asking. Thanks for the link though. :)

Comment: You mean that you want dynamically change the items in combobox? (at start you have 2: GroupA, GroupB. then you click GroupA, and items will be: A,B,C,GroupB - correct?)

Comment: No I want the single combobox items too. Including the single combobox items I need the grouping too

Comment: Well, what does `Item (GroupM) which would display A,B,C` mean? if they already displayed...i'm confused.

Comment: Two comboboxes with different `ItemsSource`: one containing only `A, B, C` and other only `X, Y, Z`? Or two comboboxes, in one you choose `M, N` and other will display (based on first one): `A, B, C` or `X, Y, Z` ?

Comment: @Sinatr I have only One ComboBox. This single combobox has single selectable items and also the GroupSlectionItems.

Comment: @MaKCbIMKo: I mean that instead of clicking each single selection items A,B,C i want the user the privilege to select a Group(M) so it would display all rows related to A,B,C in addition to the single selection itemm

Comment: `privilege to select a Group(M) so it would display all rows related to A,B,C` - display where?

Comment: Please find the screen shot i created and added here. Maybe that would help.

Comment: It seems you want to use group headers as items and show them first. That's easy, just [use dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1605845/1997232). The dictionary should contain entries for all values (single options) and all groups (grouping elements) and their corresponding string presentation.