# Datasource Dicitionary Combobox get value selected combobox c#

Tags: c#, dictionary, combobox

my problem i that i cant read the value of the selected dictionary pair of the combobox

I have used binding for the combobox

```
comboBoxNutzungsart.DataSource = new BindingSource(Zordnung.dieListe, null);
comboBoxNutzungsart.DisplayMember = "Key";
comboBoxNutzungsart.ValueMember = "Value";
```

Here is my Dictionary "dieListe"

```
public static class Zordnung
{
    public static Dictionary<String, Double> dieListe = new Dictionary<String, double>()
    {
        {"Bitte auswählen", 0},
        {"Wohnung", 50},
        {"Büro", 
    }
}
```

Now i want the value of the chosen Key, but nothin i try success

I tried this:

```
private void comboBoxNutzungsart_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double BerechneterWert;
    string text = comboBoxNutzungsart.Text;
    double zahl = Zordnung.dieListe[text] 
}
```

but with this the whole element in the dictionary will appear  text ="[Bitte auswählen, 0]"

and with something like this

```
Dictionary<string, double> selectes = 
    (Dictionary<string, double>)comboBoxNutzungsart.SelectedItem;
```

i get a Dictionary with the selected Item how do i get the value?

Comment: You can bind `SelectedItem`  and simply use source property to get it. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1605845/1997232) as to how to bind to *dictionary*.

Comment: @RufusL i get this results out of the compiler:   comboBoxNutzungsart.Text "[Bitte auswählen, 0]" string
text "[Bitte auswählen, 0]" string  zahl 0.0 double

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the problem you're running into is that the comboBox items are all objects of type `KeyValuePair<string, double>`, but you're just accessing the `ToString()` implementation of that type when you get the `.Text` property.

What you can do is cast the item to the actual type, and then you can access the `Value` (or the `Key`):

```
private void comboBoxNutzungsart_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var selectedItem = (KeyValuePair<string, double>) comboBoxNutzungsart.SelectedItem;
    string text = selectedItem.Key;
    double zahl = selectedItem.Value;
}
```

---

**Edit**

Another thought is that if you just need the `Value`, then you could access it from `Zordnung.dieListe` by getting the `Values` as a list and accessing the item at the same index as `comboBoxNutzungsart.SelectedIndex`:

```
double zahl2 = Zordnung.dieListe.Values.ToList()[comboBoxNutzungsart.SelectedIndex];
```

Comment: Thanks your explanation and code was really helpful :)

Comment: Glad it helped. Added one more note at the bottom for another way to get the value by index.

Comment: with the second solution will "Zordnung.dieListe.Values.ToList()[comboBoxNutzungsart.SelectedIndex];" creat a list or will it take the value of the selectedIndex?

Comment: It does both: it creates a list from the values so we can access an item by index (using the selected index of the combo box)